# Socket io working in localhost but when i deploy it it is doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

Im building a scribblio clone everything works perfectly in localhost but when i deployed it to heroku it doesnt work : the server doesnt crash (i tried it by accessing a default route to check if it still working), also the the ui (react) works but the socket server doesnt send back data related to the game here are the files

connection in client (react):

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

    const IO = (playerName, picture, roomId, action) => {
// here in localhost i remplace it with http://localhost:3000
    return io('https://name.herokuapp.com/', {
        path: '/socket.io',
        query: {
            username: playerName,
            picture: picture,
            roomId: roomId,
            action: action
        }
    });
}
export default IO;
```

**server** (index.js):

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socket = require('./util/socket');


const app = express();
const ioServer = new http.createServer(app);
socket.init(ioServer);

//To check if service is alive or not
app.get("/ping", (req, res) => {
    res.send("pong");
});

/* other code */

ioServer.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    consola.success(`Listening for sockets on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
});
```

**util/socket.js**:

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const consola = require('consola');
const gameManager = require('./gameManager');

exports.init = (httpServer) => {
    const io = new Server(httpServer, {
        cors: {
            origin: "*"
        }
    });
    io.on('connection', socket => {
        consola.info("Socket connected  with " + socket.id);
        let { username, roomId, action, picture } = socket.handshake.query;

        username = username.substring(0, 18)
        const room = new gameManager.Room({ io, socket, username, roomId, action, picture })
        room.init(username);
        room.listenCords();
        room.listenToMessages();
       /* other code */
    });
 /* other code */
}
```

**Network tabs:**

for both in localhost and hosted version i get this response and they are all the same only one of them : 
[network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwuVs.png)

**in localhost i have this:**

[response in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pKKZ.png)

**in the hosted version i get this:**

[response in hosted website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8khg.png)

Comment: how you host? show us web server (r-proxy) config.

Comment: @cybercoder i solved my problem as i told you it was caused by redis so i used redis cloud i changed createClient options to `redis.createClient({url: redis://mypublicendpoint,password: process.env.REDISPASSWORD});`